# Galaxt tab 3 mini connecting to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

I want to try to test my applications I made in Android Studio on my
Samsung Galaxy tab 3 mini, which I bought for developing applications.

Unfortunately, Android Studio does not recognize my Tab 3 mini.

- I reïnstalled Adroid Studio.
- I enabled the developmer mode.
- After this I turned on the USB Debugging
- In SDK MANAGER: I downloaded the Google USB Driver
- And also downloaded the adb on http://www.teamandroid.com/download-android-usb-drivers/

Stil Android Studio does not recognize my tablet. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Samsung Devices have different Drivers : http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Comment: or just download and install Samsung Kies which should also install the correct drivers for your device.

Comment: you might need to enable the developer mode...some devices you have to go to Settings> General> About and tap the Build version 7 times.

Comment: Alécio, thanks for helping, but i already did that.
Same for Itzik, the drivers were installed.
I'm going to try to install Samsung Kies, but still, the Samsung drivers were already installed.
Thanks for helping you three :)

Comment: After installing Samsung KIES it worked. Thank you very much Aegis :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the Samsung Kies program for windows, it worked perfectly!
So I hope that people with the same problem can use this solution :)
Thanks Aegis for the answer.